# split string based on regexp

Tags: c#, regex, arrays, string, split

I want to split a string in C# that looks like

a : b : "c:d"

so that the resultant array will have

Array[0] = "a"

Array[1] = "b"

Array[2] = "c:d"

what regexp do I use to achieve the required result.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the delimiter colon is separated by whitespace, you can use \s to match the whitespace:

```
string example = "a : b : \"c:d\"";
string[] splits = Regex.Split(example, @"\s:\s");
```

Comment: Thanks Andy, that helps a great deal.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work in RegexBuddy for me

`(\w+)\s:\s(\w+)\s:\s"(\w+:\w+)"`

input

> a : b : "c:d"

matched groups

> 1. a
> 2. b
> 3. c:d

As always be careful and understand what the regex actually does. Don't just copy blindly. This matches word characters `\w`, spaces `\s`, etc. Consider what data your input will actually have in it!

Comment: Great, now he has *two* problems ;p

Comment: I got 99 problems but a regex ain't one.

Comment: I think there should be more wide solution with |..smth like:
(\w+)\s:|:\s"(\w+:\w+)" ..or kind of this